# PhoneGap development language

Tags: cordova

Sorry, although I read the official document on phoneGap, I still get confused about this:

**Issue:**

If it claims that we don't need to use different language to develop apps in various platform, then why I read this paragraph from the sites:

[Mobile Tutsplus](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/phonegap-development/)

The `PhoneGap Android` documentation provides the complete list of requirements with install instructions for each.

If you are developing for the iPhone, you will need:

**An intel-based Apple Computer**
,iPhone SDK
,Xcode
,Mac OS X Snow Leopard

It means that I still have to buy a Mac product to develop the app. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the Apple computer to compile the PhoneGap wrapper (probably written using the iPhone SDK).

The code within PhoneGap is written in HTML 5 / JavaScript and is cross-platform.

Comment: Thank u, I'll try to develop the app in another platform first, since I don not any  Mac product

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap is a framework for cross platform mobile application development. You no need to write different code base for different platforms. The same code base is used for building the  application for different platforms. But the building enviornment for each platform is different. You need a MAC book for building the application for iPhone. Otherwise you can use phoneGap build service. Just upload your code base to PhoneGap build cloud service. The build service will generate the builds for each platform. The generated builds can be downloaded from the cloud service. For more info visit https://build.phonegap.com.